# Jquery variable as parameter, link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an link_to in my view:

```
<%= link_to "#{g.nummer} #{g.bezeichnung}", icd_test_path(g, :number => "JQUERY"), remote: true, :class => "tests" %>
```

What i would like to do is to have the content of id="nummer" as parameter :number in the link_to :

```
<a id="number">12<a>
```

Jquery would look something like this:

```
$(#number).html()
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just put an `:id => 'number'` inside the `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to "#{g.nummer} #{g.bezeichnung}", 
  icd_test_path(g, :number => "JQUERY"), 
  remote: true, 
  :class => "tests",
  :id => 'number' %>
```

Comment: I dont want that it has the id => number!! I want the content of the a-tag with the id number in my link to as parameter :number

Comment: Well, it is not clear what you are asking. Even with your explanation right now.

Comment: New question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334385/add-content-of-text-field-to-link-to-as-parameter