# Add content of text-field to link_to as parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How you can see i have an link_to with an empty parameter  **:street** :

```
<%= link_to "#{g.name}", icd_test_path(g, :street => "...."), remote: true %>
```

I would like to have the content of this a-tag with the id => "form" as param :street

```
<a id="form">Boulevard</a>
```

How can i make this? Is there any solution with jquery?

I suspect my link_to should look something like this:

```
:street => $(#form).html()
```

Comment: After re-reading a few times, it's not clear what you want.  the Role of `icd_test_path` in producing your final link is unclear.  It almost seems like you need to write your own helper for your use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in `rails` itself, try this:

```
<%= link_to g.name, icd_test_path(g, :street => g.name), remote: true %>
```

If your requirement is different the please comment, I will try to get you the solution.

---

Through Jquery you can try this code:

Your link can be like:

```
<%= link_to g.name, icd_test_path(g), remote: true %>
```

Then add following javascript code:

```
$(function() {
  var href = $('#form').attr('href');
  var queryString = '?street=' +  encodeURIComponent($('#form').text());
  $('#form').attr('href', href + queryString );
});
```

Comment: The thing is, i dont need g.name, i want the content of a, in this case "boulevard"

Comment: How does that define the `id` string of the HTML entity?

Comment: @JohnSmith : Modified the answer, now try this one. It should work